# How to relate one spinner items to second spinner Items

Tags: android

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpxYK.png)[In this image, spinner value is not showing item when I clicked on it item is show and when I selects item nothing shown on spinner but value is going to server ]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OFNe.png)[This is the second image where is spinner Item]

I want to implement one code where I used two spinner and there Items which is given below code and now I want that if I select none in first spinner then second spinner will show only none item and if I select 1 in first spinner then second spinner will show only none and 1 item. Can anyone help me thank you in advance

```
       <Spinner
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_back"
        android:id="@+id/NumberOfBro"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:entries="@array/no_of_brothers"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>


        <Spinner
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_back"
        android:id="@+id/NumberOfMarriedBrother"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:entries="@array/no_of_married_Brothers"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
        android:layout_below="@+id/NumberOfBro"/> 

        <string-array name="no_of_brothers">
          <item>Select Number of Brothers</item>
          <item>None</item>
          <item>1</item>
          <item>2</item>
          <item>3</item>
          <item>4</item>
          <item>4+</item>
       </string-array>

       <string-array name="no_of_married_Brothers">
         <item>Select Number of Married Brother</item>
         <item>None</item>
         <item>1</item>
         <item>2</item>
         <item>3</item>
         <item>4</item>
         <item>4+</item>
       </string-array>
```

This is java code which I used for this spinner

```
  Spinner noOfBro = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.noOfBro);
  Spinner noOfMBros = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.noOfMBros);

  noOfBro.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
  {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, 
        int position, long l) {
        String[]resList=getResources().getStringArray
        (R.array.no_of_merried_brothers);
        String[] spList = new String[position + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i <= position; i++) {
            spList[i] = resList[i];
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
            (getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spList);
            noOfMBros.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: post your java code which you have tried ..

Comment: Please check my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

You must do it programmatically. In `OnItemSelectedListener` event of your first spinner, create array of your second spinner and set to it:

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String[] resList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.no_of_married_Brothers);
        String[] spList = new String[position + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= position; i++) {
            spList[i] = resList[i];
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spList);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151190/discussion-on-answer-by-sisa-how-to-relate-one-spinner-items-to-second-spinner-i).

Comment: This code is perfect and spinner item is there but text color is white that's why last day item was not shown

Comment: Now I have done this with ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item,spList); I used my custom spinner_dopdown_item file where I set color of spinner item